# How to formally express low confidence in data in Bayesian framework?

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior

I am trying to build a Bayesian regression model, and I am looking for a formal way to express low confidence in noisy data. I know that should be reflected in the prior specification.. I am using normally distributed priors with small variances to do this. When I do this, the posterior parameter estimates are aligned to the prior, with no influence from the data. However, the model error component is high as that is inferred from the data. So, my posterior predictive distributions are off due to the variance component, which is influenced from the data.
Basically, I want the posterior predictive distribution to be the same as the prior predictive distribution.

Thanks

Comment: 1. The prior reflects your confidence in your prior information about the parameter values, not about the data.   2.  If you want the posterior predictive distribution to be the same as the prior distribution, why analyze any data at all?  Just use the prior!

Comment: So, that was the most extreme case, but I wanted to see if that could be more formally specified that was most intuitive.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to formalize an informal term (confidence) that already has a formal meaning in statistics. "Confidence" in frequentist paradigm refers to the stability of an estimate, and the specific data are considered fixed, even if they're noisy. If there's no estimate in mind, there's no need to create a probability model: simple easy-to-interpret statistics like the sample variance, or the RMSE easily communicate signal-to-noise ratios effectively. I fail to see why Bayesian statistics are necessary.

Comment: Ok, you can think of what I am trying to do is something like model averaging. I have a prior that comes from previous information. I would like to combine that with a model informed from the data. In some data sources, where I have strong belief about the source and the credibility, I would like to assign a higher relative weighting compared to the prior. Whereas with some other data sources, that I believe are not credible enough, I would like that to take a lower weight relative to the prior.